# Getting this an error while using resvg with esbundle - ""message": "No such built-in module: ./resvgjs.win32-x64-msvc-Z3LFNTDC.node","

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, executable, esbuild

Getting this Below error while using `resvg` package to convert `svg` to `png`.

```
ERROR \[12:01:28 PM GMT+0530 +0530\]: Message - No such built-in module: ./resvgjs.win32-x64-msvc-Z3LFNTDC.node

err: {

\--

"type": "Error",

"message": "No such built-in module: ./resvgjs.win32-x64-msvc-Z3LFNTDC.node",

"stack":

Error \[ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE\]: No such built-in module: ./resvgjs.win32-x64-msvc-Z3LFNTDC.node

at new NodeError (node: internal/errors:405:5)

at embedder Require (node:internal/util/embedding:43:11)

at node_modules/@resvg/resvg-js/js-binding.js (d:\\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:1355887:109)

at \__require (d:\\CATv5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:11:50)

at node_modules/@resvg/resvg-js/index.js (d:\\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:1356011:73)

at \_require (d:\\CATv5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:11:50)

at viewer-server/base/ExportBase/ExcelExport.js (d: \\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe: 1356036:31)

at \__init (d:\\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:8:57)

at viewer-server/base/ExportBase/ExportBase.js (d:\\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:1358806:5)

at \_init (d:\\CATv5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:8:57)

at viewer-server/base/BaseController.js (d: \\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:1358880:5)

at \__init (d: \\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:8:57)

at viewer-server/routes/index.js (d:\\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:1518454:5)

at \__init (d: \\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:8:57)

at viewer-server/start.js (d: \\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:1521259:5)

at \__init (d:\\CATV5\\CATExport\\CatExport.exe:8:57)

"code": "ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE"

}
```

I'm using ESbuild to bundling my node application in a single file  https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#build-scripts

with this bundle i creates an EXE of my node application to run it without node environment - here i'm using node version 20.3.1

Here is the link for convert exe of javascript file - https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html

What happens is when create EXE and my application getting an the below error - but working when running without exe ( with code )

I have tried to add this file ./resvgjs.win32-x64-msvc-Z3LFNTDC.node in the root directory but it din't work